# Cancel selection of combobox in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a combo box and I want to throw a message with a fallback logic, in case he selects something, he should get a warning, if he presses okay it executes the logic, if he does not it should be canceled.

```
<ComboBox id="id1" change="onChange">
    <core:Item id="id2" text="A"></core:Item>
    <core:Item id="id3" text="B"></core:Item>
    <core:Item id="id4" text="C"></core:Item>
</ComboBox>
```

then I have my `messagebox` in the `onChange` function:

```
onChange: function (oEvent) {
    sap.m.MessageBox.show("Are you sure you want to do that?", {
        icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.Information,
        title: "Info",
        actions: [sap.m.MessageBox.Action.YES, sap.m.MessageBox.Action.NO],
        defaultAction: sap.m.MessageBox.Action.NO,
        onClose: function (sButton) {
            if (sButton === sap.m.MessageBox.Action.YES) {
                //execute my logic in here => that works
            } else {
                oEvent.stopPropagation(); //I tried this but this does not work
            }
        }
    });
}
```

how can I achieve that?

In other words, all I would actually need is to know what the predecessor selection of that `combobox` was.

I did not find out how to get that out of the `oEvent`.

Answer (score 2):

the approach is correct (the dialog inside the `onChange`) but you need some changes.
When SAPUI5 call the onChange method the value is already written inside your control so the `oEvent.stopPropagation();` is doing nothing at all.

What you could do is to use the `ComboBox` method `setSelectedItem(null)` that should reset the current selection (reverting the user choice).

UPDATE: I've updated the code in order to solve your request.

```
    __selectedItem: null,

    onChange: function (oEvent) {
        var that = this;
        var source = oEvent.getSource();
        var selectedItem = oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItem();
        MessageBox.show("Are you sure you want to do that?", {
            icon: MessageBox.Icon.Information,
            title: "Info",
            actions: [MessageBox.Action.YES, MessageBox.Action.NO],
            defaultAction: MessageBox.Action.NO,
            onClose: function (sButton) {
                if (sButton === MessageBox.Action.YES) {
                    //execute my logic in here => that works
                    that.__selectedItem = selectedItem;
                } else {
                    source.setSelectedItem( that.__selectedItem );
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I get the error that clearSelection() is not a function

Comment: I've updated the answer, I've tested the code and it works. The problem is that you were not saving the reference to the event source. Inside the onClose the event source is the close event (of the dialog) itself and not the event from the ComboBox

Comment: that would be maybe the approach if nothing else works, but leaving the combobox blank is not what I want

Comment: that's what you requested. What would you like to do instead?

Comment: I just answered my question by myself, I will just check the saved value in the DB and bind it on that, this works for me, anyway thanks for the help mate

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the SAP code on GitHub in `InputBase.js`, the new value is already written into the property when the event you attach to is fired. My proposal would be saving the selected value in a class variable inside your controller and reverting to this value once the user cancels to achieve your goal.

Comment: I tried doing that but for some reason that value is later undefined....

Answer (score -1):

I decided to go for the following solution, thanks anyway for all the other approaches

```
 onChange: function (oEvent) {
    var source = oEvent.getSource();
    MessageBox.show("Are you sure you want to do that?", {
        icon: MessageBox.Icon.Information,
        title: "Info",
        actions: [MessageBox.Action.YES, MessageBox.Action.NO],
        defaultAction: MessageBox.Action.NO,
        onClose: function (sButton) {
            if (sButton === MessageBox.Action.YES) {
                //execute my logic in here => that works
            } else {
                var oldSelection = oModel.getProperty(oSource.getBindingContext().getPath() + "/PropertyPath");
                switch (oldSelection) {
                case "A":
                    oSource.setSelectedItem(oSource.getItems()[0], true, true);
                    break;
                case "B":
                    oSource.setSelectedItem(oSource.getItems()[1], true, true);
                    break;
                case "C":
                    oSource.setSelectedItem(oSource.getItems()[3], true, true);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please, don't use this solution. This solution is only applicable to your specific case and it's not good when you have dynamic items. Please use my updated answer code.

Comment: in my case I won't have dynamic items, therefore I am totally fine

Comment: still, it's not a good solution, look at the proposed code above ;)